# How do you resolve the error "abort uncommitted changes" when trying to "hg merge", when there are no changes?

Tags: mercurial

I did a fresh checkout of my mercurial project and updated to the tip. I am trying to merge with another branch, but get the error `abort uncommitted changes`.

```
> hg up
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
updated to "f9e1acf1f459: <commit message>"
1 other heads for branch "<branch>"

> hg merge
abort: uncommitted changes
(use 'hg status' to list changes)

> hg status



> hg status -i



> hg status -u



> hg summary
parent: 7008:f9e1acf1f459 tip
 <message for last commit>
branch: <branch>
commit: (clean)
update: 26 new changesets, 2 branch heads (merge)

>hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.9.1)
(see https://mercurial-scm.org for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2019 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I have tried using an older version of mercurial (4.7.1), with the same results.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: It seems like something is corrupt on my PC, as I am experiencing the same problem on other repositories even after installing an older version of mercurial.

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts on what could be causing this? I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: What Mercurial extensions are you using?

Comment: No extensions, just a fresh install of tortoisehg. I did some [other tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995260/how-do-i-get-mercurial-working-on-my-ssd) and figured out that for some reason, mercurial is just not working properly on my SSD drive. But moving this repository to my HDD doesn't solve this problem either.

Comment: But if you initialize a Mercurial repo on the HD, a commit works fine?

Comment: Yes, initialising a new repo on the HDD works fine, but not on the SSD, as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995260/how-do-i-get-mercurial-working-on-my-ssd)

Comment: As a test, what happens if you try to `hg commit`? (You can strip this commit later). Curious if that does anything at all and allows you to identify what the supposed local change could possibly be. Even though status shows nothing.

Comment: If I try `hg commit`, I get `nothing changed (28554 missing files, see 'hg status')`.  Also `hg diff` with previous revision yields nothing, even though there are changed files.  If I specify a changed file to diff, it shows the changes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - (version 5.7). After searching and trying a lot of things I've found one workaround:

```
delete everything except .hg directory
hg update --clean branch-name
```

I still don't know why `hg status` shows no changes and `hg merge` aborts because there are changes