# How do I get Mercurial working on my SSD?

Tags: mercurial

I had a problem working with mercurial, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980310/how-do-you-resolve-the-error-abort-uncommitted-changes-when-trying-to-hg-merg). I eventually figured out that mercurial is just not working properly at all on my SSD drive. It works better on my secondary HDD on the same machine, but doesn't resolve my other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980310/how-do-you-resolve-the-error-abort-uncommitted-changes-when-trying-to-hg-merg).

I am using TortoiseHg 4.9.1 on Windows 10.

Doing the following works fine on the HDD:

```
hg init temp
cd temp
<create test.txt>
hg ci -A -m "test"
```

But on the SSD, I get the following message, and the file is marked as added, but not committed:

```
nothing changed (1 missing files, see 'hg status')
```

`hg status` shows the following:

```
A test.txt
```

I am not noticing any other errors on the SSD (the OS, as well as all programs, are installed on it and everything seems to be working fine). I tried a scan and repair and get no errors.

Everything was working fine for several months, but now, all of a sudden, it is just not working.

Doing the same test using git, works fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any other differences between the HDD and SSD? Same filesystem for instance?

Comment: Same file system. Both were working fine last week.

Comment: Have you run a filesystem 'scan' to verify the SSD is OK?

Comment: I tried running a disk check that found and repaired some errors. I now also ran sfc /scannow, which reports the following:

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

Comment: Running sfc /scannow a second time found no "integrity violations". Still experiencing the same issues with Mercurial though.

Comment: So I'm assuming something caused disc corruption. Is there any way to figure out which files Mercurial needs that are still corrupt/missing so that I can recover without a full OS reinstall?