# Mercurial merge fails with `uncommitted changes` when nothings is changed

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I ran the following set of commands when trying to merge `trunk` branch into my `development-branch`

```
$ hg update --clean -r development-branch
getting changed largefiles
100 largefiles updated, 569 removed
10515 files updated, 0 files merged, 2926 files removed, 0 files unresolved

$ hg summary
parent: 795359:7c79716d3cce
 commit message here
branch: development-branch
commit: (clean)
update: (current)

$ hg merge trunk
abort: uncommitted changes
(use 'hg status' to list changes)

$ hg status
$
```

I'm new to Mercurial (coming from git) and I don't understand what I have to do to fix this. I've also tried `hg purge --all`, but nothing changed.

Is there a way to fix this issue without cloning the repo again? I would like to avoid cloning the repo as it take several hours...

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980310/how-do-you-resolve-the-error-abort-uncommitted-changes-when-trying-to-hg-merg, but I can't mark it as duplicate

Comment: I flagged the question for a moderator to take a look at, maybe they will be able to mark it as a duplicate for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you resolve the error "abort uncommitted changes" when trying to "hg merge", when there are no changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980310/how-do-you-resolve-the-error-abort-uncommitted-changes-when-trying-to-hg-merg)