# Merge failed because "outstanding uncommitted changes", but "hg status" indicates there are none

Tags: mercurial

We are using Mercurial. On one of our development computers, the merge fails because of "uncommitted changes". However, "hg status" gives no output, indicating that there are no uncommitted changes.

We also ran addremove and commit, so we are quite sure that there really are no uncommitted changes.

What is going wrong here?

```
C:\Projects\code2>hg merge 5f851f70ebda
abort: uncommitted changes
(use 'hg status' to list changes)

C:\Projects\code2>hg status

C:\Projects\code2>hg sum
parent: 2255:df85970f9989 tip
 (last commit message)
branch: mybranchname
commit: (clean)
update: 3 new changesets, 3 branch heads (merge)
phases: 2 draft
```

[Related question without resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980310/how-do-you-resolve-the-error-abort-uncommitted-changes-when-trying-to-hg-merg)

Comment: in .hgrc or mercurial.ini are there any aliases for hg status which might be causing it to hide/ignore anything?

Comment: I think `hg merge --force` is a valid command although --force may be deprecated - does that make any difference?

Comment: you could also try `hg update --clean`